# What will happen to any manually installed drivers(specially network drivers) after updating to a newer version of linux OS?

Tags: drivers, network-interface, software-updates

I am having a kubuntu OS with rtl8188fu wifi adapter. The adapter only works with the driver on github of kelebek333, that too worked somehow after several attempts and I dont know how it worked.

If someone can please make it clear that what will happen if if I update my system to a newer version? Will my network drivers still be in a working condition or will it create any complications for the network adapter to work properly?

Comment: Hard to say without a crystal ball, but it's likely that it won't work and you might need to recompile it from source. But it looks like the driver is actively developed, so that will probably go relatively smooth.